# How can I empty my cell data inside a table view by pressing a button outside the table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a table view in my app with 4 different types of cells in it. I would like to be able to press a button in the nav bar (a clear button) and be able to empty the data in my cells. Some of my cells have segmented controls in them and I would like to be able to set them to zero after this button is tapped. How can I accomplish this, even for cells that are not in view but still need to be emptied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop thinking about your cells and think about your data model. When the user presses the button, you reset *the data*. You then reload the table view, and your changes are picked up by the visible cells and all future cells, because you have cleverly written your `cellForRowAt` to make the cell reflect the data.

Basically, what I've just said is more or less the golden rule of table views. You *never* operate directly on a cell; you operate on the *data* and reload the table, so that any cell that needs the data can retrieve it on demand.